# Getting error in smtp in php

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I wish to send an email from my localhost with a valid smtp server. How should I configure the xampp server?
Here is my setup:

```
<?php
$mail->isSMTP();                           
$mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;   
$mail->Username = 'myusername'; 
$mail->Password = 'my password'; 
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->From = 'noreply@mysite.com';
$mail->FromName = 'mysite';
$mail->addAddress($email, $email); 
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = 'Reset your Password';
$mail->Body    =  $content;
$mail->AltBody = $content;
$mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
?>
```

I'm getting error:

> error:"called HELO without being connected".

All variables are set, but I left some out to shorten the question.

Comment: Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` and post the output.

Comment: @Synchro. thank's. I think some thing wrong with the pass, doesn't it?
`SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed`.`SMTP connect() failed`

Comment: Post the whole output.

Comment: @Synchro. I can't add the whole of the output but I add here some of them.

Comment: The problem will be happening some time before that error, so having just the error message is no use.

Comment: You don't have to do it like that - edit and add it to your question and format it so it's readable. Overall though that just looks like a legitimate incorrect password.